# XGBoost Predictions

Tags: machine-learning, classification, xgboost, multiclass-classification

I am working on a multi-class classification task for 24 classes using XGBoost. I am training the model as follows:

```
param = {'max_depth': max_depth, 'eta': learning_rate, 'silent': 1, 'objective': 'multi:softmax', 'num_class': 24}
bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, num_round)
bst = xgb.Booster({'nthread': 4})
predictions = bst.predict(dval)
```

I am getting the predictions as this array:

```
[ 0.5  0.5  0.5 ...,  0.5  0.5  0.5]
```

I don't know why it's predicting all classes as 0.5 instead of one of the indices in 0 to 23. Do I need to use any other objective parameter?

Comment: What is the line bst = xgb.Booster({'nthread': 4}) for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know python API, but I guess with the following line you overwrite the trained object with a freshly created booster object (0.5 is a default prediction)

```
bst = xgb.Booster({'nthread': 4})
```

Comment: Worked! I thought this would train using 4 threads.